# Facebook Graph calls to me/photos now return "Unsupported get request." though I've made no changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm getting an error when trying to retrieve Facebook Graph photos.

The same query works on the [dev sandbox](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/)

This wasn't a problem yesterday, and appears to be a problem on my production server to which I haven't updated the code. I don't believe I've changed any significant app settings recently (new icon a week ago).

This feels like a change on Facebook's side. I'm happy to investigate more on my side, and hopeful of finding a workaround.

**Library using to access**

Node.JS via [criso::fbgraph](https://criso.github.io/fbgraph/)

**Library options**

```
{ timeout: 3000,
  pool: { maxSockets: Infinity },
  headers: { connection: 'keep-alive' } }
```

**API Version**

Originally built with 2.5.  Same error on 2.4, 2.5 & 2.6

**Path**

`me/photos?fields=id,album,images,name,name_tags,tags`

**Response error**

```
{ message: 'Unsupported get request.',
  type: 'GraphMethodException',
  code: 100,
  fbtrace_id: 'GO8G+a2e3Eg' }
```

Comment: debug the user token and make sure it is still valid

Comment: @luschn Locally I reset my database between tests; all Facebook tokens are fresh. It also appears other API calls go through, which I think use the same token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but removing `name_tags` makes it work. Maybe an (undocumented?) Facebook API or permissions change.

**New (working) path**

me/photos?fields=id,album,images,name,tags